# sudo is not working properly

Tags: sudo, pip

```
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Comment: What command prompted this error message?

Comment: sudo pip install virtualenv

Comment: @Ashok I would actually recommend doing `sudo apt install virtualenv` to install `virtualenv` system-wide.

Comment: This is *not* a problem of `sudo`.

Comment: then what would be problem to cause the above error?  And how do i solve it???

Comment: Did you try installing with -H as suggested from the error? `sudo -H pip install virtualenv`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting warning file permission with root user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/872940/getting-warning-file-permission-with-root-user)